# Pod related to job execution never gets terminated even after exitcode 0

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes

I am running a Go application (like a CLI) using a Kubernetes job.

deployment.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: $DEPLOY_NAME
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 2592000
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: $DEPLOY_NAME
          image: $DEPLOY_IMAGE
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: "0.02"
              memory: 590Mi
            limits:
              cpu: "1"
              memory: 756Mi
      restartPolicy: Never
```

On the go application I am putting

```
func main() {
    defer func() {
        os.Exit(0)
    }()
    //code to execute
}
```

But the job never gets completed (or failed) and the pod keeps running (even without anything to execute anymore)

I don't want to add `activeDeadlineSeconds` because the execution could take 5 minutes or 5 days. I want to end the execution by myself telling to kubernetes that I have finished the execution.

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` is maybe your problem. Try it without that.

Comment: @akop I tried this (even knowing that should have no impact on the pod itself) but even after removing the flag the pod keeps having the same behaviour.

Comment: Ah I see, I read the docs and saw my mistake. Are you sure, that the process was terminated?

Comment: the pod never gets terminated, the pod status is always "Running" and I am using `exit(0)`. The application ends and stops showing logs but the pod never gets completed neither the job.

Comment: I have not asked for the pod, I asked for the process. I'm not familiar with Go, but I would guess, that your application not correctly terminated. Can you run your docker-image locally and check, if it stopped correctly?